# Необходимо сделать выборку из 4 столбцов, что бы на выходе получить 3 столбца

Tags: python, pandas

Ломаю голову уже неделю. Имеется 4 столбца, по 2 столбца из двух датафреймов.
Необходимо найти уникальные значения при сравнении столбца df1['Имя'] и df2['Имя 2'].
Важно, что бы значения столбца df1['Возраст'] и df2['Специальность'] были привязаны к значениям df3['Имя'], что бы они не потерялись при сравнении.
Что бы в итоге получилось 3 столбца, уникальные имена в столбце df3['Имя'], df3['Возраст'], df3['Специальность'].

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Имя': ['Сергей', 'Владимир', 'Александр', 'Евгений', 'Анна', 'Татьяна', 'Ирина', 'Ольга', 'Елена', 'Сергей'],
         'Возраст': [20, 25, 35, 28, 35, 41, 45, 30, 42, 46],}

data2 = {
      'Имя': ['Александр', 'Сергей', 'Евгений', 'Объект', 'Объект', 'Объект', 'Татьяна', 'Объект', 'Объект', 'Объект'],
      'Специальность': ['Программист', 'Строитель', 'Монтажник', 'Инженер', 'Домохозяйка', 'Повар', 'Швея', 'Врач', 'Актриса', 'Программист'],}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(list(range(10)))

df3[['Имя', 'Возраст']] = df1.loc[:, ['Имя', 'Возраст']]

df3[['Имя 2', 'Специальность']] = df2.loc[:, ['Имя', 'Специальность']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то `DataFrame.merge` это то что вам нужно:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Имя': ['Сергей', 'Владимир', 'Александр', 'Евгений', 'Анна', 'Татьяна', 'Ирина', 'Ольга', 'Елена', 'Сергей'],
         'Возраст': [20, 25, 35, 28, 35, 41, 45, 30, 42, 46],}

data2 = {
      'Имя': ['Александр', 'Сергей', 'Евгений', 'Объект', 'Объект', 'Объект', 'Татьяна', 'Объект', 'Объект', 'Объект'],
      'Специальность': ['Программист', 'Строитель', 'Монтажник', 'Инженер', 'Домохозяйка', 'Повар', 'Швея', 'Врач', 'Актриса', 'Программист'],}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

df1.merge(df2, on='Имя')
```

```
Out[1]:
        Имя Возраст Специальность
    0   Сергей  20  Строитель
    1   Сергей  46  Строитель
    2   Александр   35  Программист
    3   Евгений 28  Монтажник
    4   Татьяна 41  Швея
```

Если это не совсем то что вам нужно, то поэксперементируйте с параметром `how` функции `merge`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все получилось.